# Использование combobox для подключения к разным таблицам бд в приложении Winforms C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Пишу приложение для подключения к бд и управления данными. Был найден код, в котором написали подключение к одной таблице бд и жестко привязали к DataGridView, добавил классы для других таблиц и все что нужно для подключения. Столкнулся с проблемой выгрузки в DGV. Изначально данные грузились в MainForm_Load:

```
        private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _repo = new MySqlRepository();
        //Подгрузка данных
        LoadDataAdm();
        //кнопки
        _buttonAdd.Click += ButtonAdd_Click;
        _buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
        _buttonSave.Click += ButtonSave_Click;
        _buttonNext.Click += ButtonNext_Click;
        _buttonPrev.Click += ButtonPrev_Click;
        //клик по строке в DGV
        _dataGridViewSelecNow.MouseClick += (s, a) => SetCurrentAdmin();
    }
```

Метод подгрузки:

```
        private async void LoadDataAdm()
    {
        var result = await _repo.GetAdmins();
        if (result)
        {
            //извлекаем
            List<Admins> admins = result.Value;
            //отображаем
            _bsCur.DataSource = admins;
            _bsCur.MoveFirst();
            SetCurrentAdmin();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.Error, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

После этого как я понял, происходила привязка к DGV.

```
        public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Text = "Бд АВТОШКОЛА";
        //Привязка
        SetBindingsAdm();

        this.Load += MainForm_Load;
    }
```

Метод привязки:

```
        private void SetBindingsAdm()
    {
        _bsCur = new BindingSource();
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            _bsCur.DataSource = typeof(List<Admins>);
            _dataGridViewSelecNow.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            _dataGridViewSelecNow.DataSource = _bsCur;

            _bsCurCur = new BindingSource();
            _bsCurCur.DataSource = new List<Admins> { new Admins(0) };
        }
```

Я пытался произвести проверку для подргрузки нужных данных, например здесь

```
        public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Text = "Бд АВТОШКОЛА";

        //установка привязок
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            SetBindings();
        }
        else
        {
            SetBindingsAdm();
        }
        SetBindings();

        this.Load += MainForm_Load;
    }
```

[image: Комбобокс]
Вроде разобрался, что сначала происходит выполнение в MainForm_Load, после же в MainForm(). Менял очередность методов, не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такую обработку?

UPD:
В проблеме разобрался следующим образом, все оказалось очень проще:

```
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            LoadDataEmp();
        }
    }
```

Comment: В конструкторе не должно быть ничего лишнего. Весь код из конструктора перенесите в события `Load`, `Shown`.

Comment: Перенес код, работоспособность нарушена. Дело скорее всего в том что изначально нужно выполнить метод SetBindings(), а после этого LoadData(), при помещении в метод Load обоих, возникает исключение System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. в методе LoadData(). Я думаю происходит это потому что метод Load асинхронный, и выполняется раньше в отдельном потоке, что и вызывает исключение. Не могу понять как выполнить код бинда раньше чем код загрузки данных, убрать асинхронность или создать очередь?

Comment: Что помешало добавить то чно нужно из конструктора в самое начало? Сделать вызываемый метод `async Task` и использовать тупо `await`? Не используйте `async void` нигде кроме как в обработчиках. Это хреновая ошибка.

Comment: Попробовал сегодня утром, получилось, правда выбрасывало исключение о привязке двух коллекций с текстбоксами, буду разбираться. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: _разобрался, что сначала происходит выполнение в MainForm_Load, после же в MainForm()_ - нет! Сперва выполняется конструктор, затем - события.

Comment: [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) - полезная ссылка - очерёдность событий.